# Why categorical_crossentropy gives 16?

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function, cross-entropy

I'm trying to calculate the math behind the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np



y_pred_one_hot = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1], dtype='float32')
y_true_one_hot = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0], dtype='float32')


res = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true_one_hot,y_pred_one_hot,from_logits=False)
round(res.numpy() , 3)
```

gives =
16.118

I'm using the equation:

[image]

1. log(0)  is error ? so how I'm getting 16 ?
2. ti and pi have 0 in same indexes, so the sum doesn't need be 0 ?

what am I missing behaind the math ?

Comment: That's not the exact equation being used, frameworks add a small epsilon to prevent log(0)

Comment: To add to the answer from Dr. Snoopy, p_i gets clipped in the range of [eps, 1-eps] before the log() happens. You get 16.118 in index 1, with `1*ln(1e-7)`, with eps=1e-7 in TF.